# Why specify class name when declaring member functions?

Tags: c++, class

```
class C : public B
{
public:
    void C::Test();
};
```

What is the point of specifying `C` in the declaration of the member function?

Comment: we used to do it because it made cut/paste and searching between the definition/declaration easier. But with modern IDEs there is no need  and it's now illegal.

Comment: @Martin Becket: Strictly speaking, it was already illegal even in C++98. Even if there was a time when it was legal, it must have been  some pre-standard period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't do this. Many modern compilers will treat this as a syntax error, for example, g++ 4.2.1 will!

Answer (score 2):

This is only neccessary when defining the method outside of the class:

```
class C : public B
{
public:
    void Test();
};

void C::Test() { ... }
```

Comment: But not when declaring it *inside* the class definition, as your example seems to imply.

Comment: What do you mean (pehaps you refer to an erroneous post, which I edited shortly after posting, actually copy-and-pasted from the question and forgot to remove the error).

Comment: Yes, I referred to the earlier version. Looks fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Not only there's no point, it is downright illegal (see 8.3/1 in the language standard). In general in C++ language *qualified names* are allowed only when you are referring to a *previously declared* entity, but not when you are introducing a new entity (there are some exceptions from this rule, but none of them apply here).

The code you posted would require a diagnostic message from any conforming compiler, since your member function declaration is invalid.

Comment: I know it's illegal, but I'm failing to find why. Is there a note somewhere, or is it in the grammar?

Comment: @GMan: It is in 8.3/1. Basically, qualified names can only be used to refer to *previously declared* entities, but not to introduce new entities. See also this defect: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#482. The old (defective) wording was more explicit, but with regard to this example nothing really changed in the new wording.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point, no need to do this. Since the declaration of `Test` is inside the scope of the declaration of `C`, the compiler knows that the function `Test` is a member of `C`.